# Running an MVC application through IIS results in "Directory listing denied"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, webproject

I have an .Net MVC application which runs fine if I use the build in Visual Studio Webserver. If I use the projects property pages to switch to IIS as the webserver and create a virtual directory for my project, any request I send to the server results in a "Directory listing denied" failure.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with 'extensionless' urls prior to IIS7.

It needs either an ISAPI filter or duplicate routes in the routing table with a .mvc extension. Try ScottGu's blog at weblogs.asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the IIS does not have default.aspx set up as a start page.